# Phonegap Push Plugin is not working giving uncaught type error in Android

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I am working to get Push Notification in my Hybrid mobile Application build using JQuery Mobile wrapped with Cordova.

I am using Phonegap Push Plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) to facilitate notification functionality in my Application. When I call the init method of the plugin like below, it gives the exception which is stated below the init call.

```
var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "XXxxXXxxCXPLcIV0eay5x3mfuQKValzvDT_xxxxxx"},
     "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );

Uncaught TypeError: Object function (options) {
    this._handlers = {
        'registration': [],
        'notification': [],
        'error': []
    };

    // require options parameter
    if (typeof options === 'undefined') {
        throw new ...<omitted>...t' index.js:135
registerForPushNotification index.js:135
(anonymous function) index.js:80
n.event.dispatch jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
r.handle jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
n.event.trigger jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
(anonymous function) jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
n.extend.each jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
n.fn.n.each jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
n.fn.extend.trigger jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
a.Widget._trigger jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
a.Widget._createWidget jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
a.widget._createWidget jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
a.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
n.extend.each jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
n.fn.n.each jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
a.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
a.widget.transition jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
a.widget.change jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
n.extend.each jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
n.fn.n.each jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
a.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
a.mobile.changePage jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
a.mobile.gradeA.a.extend.initializePage jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:15451
j jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
k.fireWith jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
n.extend.ready jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2
```

To call the init method, I got the file `push.js` from the `plugins/phonegap-plugin-push/www/push.js` and placed in project `www` folder. Also referenced the same in `index.html`

The version of Android project created is,

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Thanks for you help in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using `API_KEY` "XXxxXXxxCXPLcIV0eay5x3mfuQKValzvDT_xxxxxx" as `senderID`. Please re-check this thing.

Comment: I also tried using Project number (XXXX4969XXXX) and Project ID (myproject-X0X0) but results the same

Comment: Can you please tell me about Android Support Library version & Android Support Repository version, which you are using ?

Comment: My Android Support Library version  is 23.0.1 and Android Support Repository version is 21.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the answer by adding the following in my config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />

    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

<platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>

<platform name="ios">
      <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

Yes, Cordova CLI created these when creating the project. My project was created months back and didn't had these. Thanks for your help.

Also make sure the plugin source folder is not inside your project.